# PySpark: How to check if list of string values exists in dataframe and print values to a list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a df **NAMES** in which if I output via `display(NAMES)`:

```
NAMES

John

Sarah

Michael

Sean
```

I also have a list  **students**, `print(students)`:

{John, Alan, Andy}

**Question**:

Based on this list (students), how can I loop through the df with "NAMES" Column and output to another list the names of students who are in the list and also in the DF.

Expected output of list: "John"

**I have tried**

```
list2 = []
for i in NAMES:
     for g in students:
        if i == g:
          list2.append(i)
```

but i end up with an error, how can i implement this via pyspark?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does this have to do with `pyspark`?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general looping through data in `pyspark` will not be very efficient.  When possible use native `pyspark` functions.  For your specific question you can use the `filter` function that will filter your DataFrame by names in the student list:

```
df_names.filter(col("name").isin(students)).select("name")
```

In your example the only return value will be John.